# tracking google search volume?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search

Is there a way to track the actual search volume for keywords on a regular basis, even if this search volume might be quite low (maybe a few 100 searches per month)? 
I was wondering if google has an API for this. I know they have the keyword search volume tool but I thought this doesn't give accurate numbers and no numbers at all when the volume is too small.
Thanks,
B

Comment: I think you can have this kind of info on Webmaster Tools but only if it's relevant to your website. It won't give you any keyword you want, and all data is probably aproximate.